# How to promote your new website (when you have an old site with the same theme but higher PR)

Tags: redirects, keywords, google-ranking

In the situation that you have an old website registered under wordpress (for example aaa.wordpress.com). It became quite successful and you decided to purchase "aaa.com".

On aaa.com, you continued talking about the same topic same from "aaa.wordpress.com", and we put links from "aaa.wordpress.com" to "aaa.com". but because "aaa.wordpress.com" was so successful before, that your keyword ranking for "aaa.com" is always behind.

How can we increase the keyword ranking for "aaa.com"?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress.com offers [domain mapping](http://en.support.wordpress.com/add-a-domain/#i-already-have-a-domain) so there is no need to start a new blog (if you intend to keep the one on Wordpress.com).

Also, here is a forum thread regarding [domain mapping and SEO](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/is-domain-mapping-better-for-seo).